# Effect on application's performance when use multiple subject [rxjs]

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

My question is regarding to Application's performance.
I'll explain my situation with below example.

**example:**

I have five components.All the components are in parent-child relationship.For data transfer I used service. In my service I have more than fifty(50) variable like `isSend=new Subject();`. Now I am emitting (fifty variable's) value from the same service then I subscribe all this event emitter in the components `onInit` method.

**Is it effect on my application's performance or it is good practice to transfer the data.Need help.**

Comment: If you have 50 variables - like one mentioned in your question - I think you have more of a maintenance issue than a performance issue.

Comment: Of course this will have effects on the performance. Especially on older Computers with IE where Polyfills are used. Do you see any change in reducing the amount of variables?

Comment: Multiple subjects wont be a problem: it is more likely that re-rendering caused by the values coming out of those subjects being prohibitive. As long as all those Subjects deliver their data in the same tick (eg without a setTimeout in between) then that should cause a single render, probably making it ok.

Comment: Okay guys. i'll try to reduce number of variable in the same service.